# this sentence containing an attributive phrase or is it 2 separate sentences with an omitted comma in between

Tags: interpretation

I found this paragraph with a translation:

> この選択に至った理由はたくさんありますが、全て私の意思であり、その意思をKONAMI様は尊重して契約解除を決定して下さいました。
>   I have many reasons for reaching this conclusion but it is all my decision. I am grateful for Konami for respecting that decision.

I don't know how to interpret this part :

> その意思をKONAMI様は尊重して契約解除を決定して下さいました。

Is その意思をKONAMI様は尊重して modifying 契約解除?  because I don't know how to parse it to match the translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is その意思をKONAMI様は尊重して modifying 契約解除? because I don't know how to parse it to match the translation

My quick answer is:

> 1. その意思をKONAMI様は尊重して is not modifying 契約解除.
> 2. It is impossible to parse the given Japanese to match the translation in English.

I'm going to tell you why.

> その意思をKONAMI様は尊重して契約解除を決定して下さいました。

The given sentece is literally interpreted as (A) or (B).

- (A) KONAMI様はその（＝私の）意思を尊重して、（そして、）契約解除を決定して下さいました。
  *Mr. KONAMI respected my decision and decided to cancel the contract.*
- (B) KONAMI様はその（＝私の）意思を尊重したので、契約解除を決定して下さいました。
  *Since Mr. KONAMI respected my decision, he decided to cancel the contract*.
  or
  *Mr. KONAMI respected my decision, so he decided to cancel the contract*.

> I am grateful for Konami for respecting that decision.

原文{げんぶん}は前半｛ぜんはん｝と後半｛こうはん｝とで主語｛しゅご｝が異｛こと｝なります。後半｛こうはん｝の主語｛しゅご｝はKONAMI様です。
翻訳者{ほんやくしゃ}は原文｛げんぶん｝の後半｛こうはん｝の主語｛しゅご｝を前半｛ぜんはん｝に合｛あ｝わせるように変更｛へんこう｝して、かつ意訳｛いやく｝しています。
*In the original sentence, the subject is different in the first half and the second half*. *The latter subject is Mr. KONAMI*.
*The translator changed the subject of the latter half of the original sentence to match that of the first half and made a free/liberal translation*.

This interpretation could be, if the given sentence is rewritten from the standpoint of "me" and add "my" gratitude for his decision.
I think the person who translated this sentence into English was skillful in understanding of Japanese.